# jQuery toggle div: have below content to slide "gently"

Tags: javascript, html, slidetoggle, jquery

I use this script to toggle a div with an animation. It works like a charm, except that the content below the div to toggle moves jumpy when .click is triggered.

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $toggled = $(this).attr('href');

$($toggled).siblings('.gallery:visible').hide();
    $($toggled).toggle("slide", {direction: 'up'}, 750);
    return false;
});
```

How can I have the content below to slide "gently" (as content of toggled div does)? Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Try to add on complete handler of the slidup that make one div(gallery) only to be visible but with opacity 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your call to `.toggle` with regards to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). The order of parameters, their values, just don't match the documentation.

I have tried to use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) - it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try use thumbnails instead.

Use any program to change their size to the "slidedown" size. Change the `<img>` src to the thumbnail (smaller image) and change the `<a>` url to the actual size.

The website is loading the large size and then rezise them. This is my best guess why its feels laggy correct me if im wrong.

Good luck!

Hint: Try using a small image on every slot before you create thumbnails and see if it is actually causing the trouble.

Comment: Uhm.. but original size is 1.024px × 681px (I know it's wrong but it's a "work in progress", I'll resize 'em later.) ... I don't think it's loading that size and then resize 'em (the block would be huge).

Comment: It is loading the original size of the image, not the size you want them to show. For this im 100% sure. If it is causing the lagging, im not sure. For testing, try using a small image on every slot and see if its still lagging.

Comment: Yep, for loading I meant "in screen". Of course the browser is loading original size.

Comment: I explained very badly. My apologies. I dont mean it show original and then resize. But go ahead and try my suggestion and see if it helps